# DOM does not match PHP output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following PHP script:

```
    function drawDepts(mysqli $con, $defaultDept) {

    $deptQuery = "SELECT * FROM depts";
    $deptResult = $con->query($deptQuery);
    global $request;

    echo "<select id='targetDept' width='200' style='width:200px;' onchange='updateRequest(".$request['id'].", 'targetDept', $('#targetDept').val()'>";

    while ($deptRow = $deptResult->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $deptRow['id'] . "' ";
        if ($deptRow['id'] == $defaultDept) {
            echo "selected='selected'";
        }
        echo ">" . $deptRow['name'] . "</option>";
    }

    echo "</select>";
}
```

This basically just creates a select box with options from a DB. The onchange allows the user to update the DB without re-loading the page (ajax).

The weird part is the DOM shows this (IE 11):

```
<select id="targetDept" style="width: 200px;" onchange="updateRequest(212, " $('#targetdept').val())'="" targetdept',="" width="200">
```

Specifically, why are there `"` , `=""` and `width="200px"`

echoing the javascript function as text works just fine... It seems that IE is screwing up the `onchange` tag.

Comment: The issue is because you're using `'` to delimit the `onchange` attribute and also the `targetDept` string within that. It's a syntax error. You need to escape the inner string, or better yet attach your event handlers using Javascript instead of ugly `on*` attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error on your `onchange` with `'` and `"` use `\` to escape the `'` used within your `onChange` with the `'`'s

```
echo "<select id='targetDept' width='200' style='width:200px;' onchange='updateRequest(".$request['id'].", \"targetDept\", $(\"#targetDept\").val())'>";
```